# Solr filter queries and boosting

Tags: solr

Is it possible to boost fields that appear in filter queries (fq=) in Solr?

I have a faceted query that has a tagged filter query something like this:

```
...&q=*:*&fq={!tag:X}brand:(+"4911")+OR+body:(abc)&facet.field={!ex:X}brand&..
```

(I facet on brand and the facet is set to ignore the filter query tagged X, so I need to use a filter query.)

I would like to make matches on the brand field score higher than matches on body field in the filter query.

The fields brand and body are multivalued.

I've tried adding bf=/bq= arguments, and I can get brand matches to score higher if I change the filter query to be the main 'q=' query, but I don't seem to be able to influence the score of anything in the filter query.  I think I maybe going about it in the wrong way..

Thanks.

Comment: Here: [link](http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/77a17b1bad16acd8/boost_the_results_for_filter_value_in_a_single_query) is what I'm trying to do as suggested by Yonik Seeley, but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: I can't find any way of letting the fq scores influence the order of results.  I have managed to get the results I want using a sort query. I adding something like '&qq=brand:(4911)&sort=sum(query($qq),ord(score))+desc' but I think it may have an effect on performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solr "fq"'s do not affect score -- see [the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq). So, you should add your queries to "q" that you actually want to boost. If need be, you can always duplicate a query restriction in both "q" and "fq", as "fq" only acts as a restriction on the results set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Indeed filter queries do not affect the score, I didn't know that at the start.  I was wondering if it was possible with the 'bq' boost query param of the dismax parser.   My final solution was to use two requests. One for faceting and the other for the ordered results.